# The XML page cannot be displayed ,What is the cause of this error?

Tags: html, xml

I have following page with code as below embeded in JSP.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>B2E</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/global.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/local.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/calendarControl.css">
<script language="JavaScript" src="../jscripts/calendarControl.js"></script>
<script src="../jscripts/ajaxAction.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="../jscripts/ajaxMaster.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table border = "0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width = "100%">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="100%" bgcolor=""><img height="" src="../images/spacer.gif" width="100%"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" colspan="100%" align = "left" class="headerbg" height="30">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="100%" bgcolor=""><img height="" src="../images/spacer.gif" width="100%"></td>
            </tr>
</table>
<%//@ include file="../includes/mainTheme.jsp"%>
<form action="" name="f"> 
<table align ="right">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="vs" value="" size="30" class="small"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="Find" onclick="return check()" class="small"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="greysmall">(Enter visitor name/company name)</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
    <table border = "0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width = "100%">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="100%" bgcolor=""><img height="1" src="../images/spacer.gif" width="100%"></td>
            </tr>
    </table>
<br>

<table border = "0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width = "100%" style="background-color:#9900FF" height="30">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="" bgcolor="">&nbsp;</td>
            <td colspan="" bgcolor="" ><a href="javascript:void();" class="boldsmall" onclick="goHome()" style="color:#FFFFFF">Home</a></td>
            <td colspan="" bgcolor="" ><a href="javascript:void();" class="boldsmall" onclick="createNew()" style="color:#FFFFFF">Create Visit</a></td>
            <td colspan="" bgcolor="" ><a href="javascript:void();" class="boldsmall" onclick="scheduleVisit()" style="color:#FFFFFF">Schedule Visit</a></td>
            <!--<td colspan="" bgcolor=""><a href="javascript:void();" class="boldsmall">Other Administrative Tasks</a></td>-->
            <td colspan="" bgcolor="" ><a href="javascript:void();" class="boldsmall" onclick="showAllVisitor()" style="color:#FFFFFF">All Visitors</a></td>
            <td colspan="" bgcolor="" ><a href="javascript:void();" class="boldsmall" onclick="showExVisitor()" style="color:#FFFFFF">Exited Visitors</a></td>
            <td colspan="" bgcolor="" ><a href="javascript:void();" class="boldsmall" onclick="showScheduleVisitor()" style="color:#FFFFFF">Scheduled Visitors</a></td>
            <td colspan="" bgcolor="" ><a href="javascript:void();" class="boldsmall" onclick="showBlackVisitor()" style="color:#FFFFFF">Black List Visitors</a></td>
            <td colspan="" bgcolor="" ><a href="javascript:void();" class="boldsmall" onclick="launchBox();" style="color:#FFFFFF">Daily Visitors</a></td>

        </tr>
</table>
<br>
<table border = "0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width = "100%">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="100%" bgcolor=""><img height="1" src="../images/spacer.gif" width="100%"></td>
        </tr>
</table>
<div id="txtHint" class="small" align="center" style="overflow:">

</div>
<br/>
<%//@ include file="../includes/footer.jsp"%>

<%response.setContentType("text/xml");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
%>
</body>
</html>
```

when I process this page on Tomcat web server I am running into  following error.

[image]

I am unable to solve this .
What is the cause of this error?

as Error suggest `>` expected , but there is no need to to place more `>` as it is alreadily closed properly.

Comment: Probably because you're missing closing tag(s) for at least one element such as `<br>` or `<img>`. In a well-formed xml each node needs to be closed using either the closing tag (`<br></br>`) or auto closing the tag (`<br />`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your link tags are not closed, nor are all of your break tags and image tags.

Fixed Example:

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/global.css"/>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/local.css"/>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/calendarControl.css"/>
```